# WP_Query With meta_query and Value of Custom Field as 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I am experiencing some unexpected behavior. I have added a custom filed of "Rating" to my posts. I want to count up the number of posts with a certain rating:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'rating',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => 7
        )   
    )
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
echo $posts->post_count;
```

When I set the value to 7, it echos the correct number of posts for that rating. But for some reason, if I set the value to 0, it echos the total number of published posts. What am I missing?

Comment: could be a filter is interpreting the 0 as a bool, try prefixing with (int)0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little digging and this appears to be dude to PHP's "empty" function. This is slated to be fixed in WordPress 3.2. Details here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15292

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but when I need it I just use compare = '<=' value = '0.5'

I think wordpress use 0 as empty or null var, instead of actually zero.